Is the word "boy" racist in the following situation?
I watched part of a movie a very long time ago. In it, a lone Eastern Asian adult male of average height asks a very tall white man where the washroom is. The white man replies:

Over there. For boys.

He's a native English speaker. The tone's normal. They're strangers to each other. They're in North America.
I wonder if the word “boy” has any racist meaning in it. I know it does for black men, but I don’t know if it does for Asian men.
Racism aside, is that reply rude in another way? Can you call a man a “boy” in situations like that? I know in some situations you can call a man a “boy” without any derogatory meaning. But for the reply in the movie, is the word “boy” derogatory?
It’s a long time ago and I only watched a little bit of the movie. I don’t even remember its name. So that’s all the context I got.

I’m voting to close this question because the speaker directs a man to the bathroom. He does not address the man as boy.

Could you add a line saying whether the emphasis (bold, italic) is yours, or whether it's in the original?  (I'm guessing it's yours, if “The tone's normal”, but it would be good to confirm since it's so relevant.)

Is "for boys" here intended to clarify that the one "for girls" is somewhere else?

@gidds, no, I didn't add the emphasis. Somebody else edited my post without my permission and added that, causing the confusion. I've changed it back now.

@Mark Dominus, no, because the Asian's alone. I said earlier in a comment under one of the answers below: "the white male understands that the Asian's asking about a men's washroom, because the Asian's alone and because if he's asking about a women's washroom, he'd make it clear." But now all the comments have been moved to chat by a mod.

As has been noted before on this site (by WS2 and Matt E. Эллен), little girls' room and little boys' room are common euphemisms for toilets. The playfulness of that use of the terms is intended to make it less vivid what is really referred to, and nothing more: it does not imply that there is anything in any way girlish/boyish about those who may avail themselves of that amenity, nor is it in any way associated with the racist use of boy. The use of the phrase for boys that the OP describes may be derived from the use of little boys' room as a euphemism for a men's toilet (the speaker may have felt the need to make it clear that this is where the men's toilet was, because the women's toilet was elsewhere).
Of course it is possible that the word was intended as a put-down (racist or otherwise) in that particular case, but to argue that it was, one would need to know more about the context and the overall social setting than the OP provides.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

While it has been common in America for racists to call black men "boy", it did not extend to other non-white races, so a white man would be unlikely to consider an Asian man a boy.
In addition, I don't think they usually used the epithet in contexts other than directly addressing a black man. If there were separate restrooms, water fountains, bus seats, etc. for whites and blacks, they wouldn't say that the one for blacks is for boys. They'd be more likely to use the N-word, or if they don't want to be so crude they might say something like "for you folks".
So in your example, I think they're just distinguishing the boy's room from the girl's room, not from a white men's room.

The term "houseboy" used to be used for a servant who was a person of colour. I no longer have a copy of The Skylark of Space, a science fiction novel published 100 years ago, but I do recall one of the main characters having a Japanese houseboy.

True, but I don't think that's related to the racist use of "boy" for black men in the US. I think "houseboy" is mostly a UK term.

thinks that "houseboy" is mostly a UK term`. That would explain why an American science fiction writer was using it for a Japanese in the 1920s'-)

Well, "mostly". And I stand by my claim that it's unrelated to the use of "boy" as a derogatory term for a black man. Except tangentially -- most uses of "boy" for men tend to suggest lower social status (exception, I think: the "best boy" job in filmmaking).

You can "stand by your claim" as much as you like, because it does not appear to be based on evidence. About 40 years ago I lived in the Solomon Islands, which had gained its independence 5 years before, and I can assure you that "boy" had been used in a derogatory sense in the not too distant past. The servants quarters were called "the boyhouse", despite the fact that most expats, and those locals who could afford it, had housegirls.

One of the OED's definitions of boy says that it was:

1a.ii Used (chiefly by white people) with reference to non-white slaves and (in English-speaking colonies) to non-white servants, labourers, etc. Also as a form of address (esp. as a summons). Now historical and rare (usually considered offensive).
A non-white male. Now usually considered offensive (as being associated with sense 1a.ii).

Though.co has a post about racist words, and this is what it says under boy:

In most situations, the word "boy" is not a problem. Used to describe a Black man, however, the word is troublesome. That's because historically, White people routinely described Black men as boys to suggest they weren't on equal footing with them.
Despite its widespread use as a racial putdown, in Ash v. Tyson Foods, the U.S. Court of Appeals decided that "boy" cannot be considered a racial slur unless it's prefaced with a racial marker such as "Black." This decision has sparked controversy, considering that White people typically didn't call anyone "Black boys" during Jim Crow, but simply "boys."
The good news, according to Prerna Lal of Change.org, is that the U.S. Supreme Court reversed the holding, ruling that

the use of the word 'boy' on its own is not enough evidence of racial animus, but that the word is also not benign.

That means the court is willing to consider the context in which "boy" is used to determine if it's being uttered as a racial epithet.

Boy is not commonly used to refer specifically to Asian people in a racist way. It is not included in Wikipedia's List of ethnic slurs, which of course may not be thorough but usually gives you a gist of common usage.
Now, without more context, it is difficult to pinpoint the intention of the speaker when using the word boys in his answer to this Asian stranger. One could understand it as a humorous way of saying 'Gents'. And since the white male probably uses the same washroom, the term 'boys' can't be too derogatory because he identified himself with that category.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Possibly a different kind of rudeness
Without knowing the film, the scene, or the intonation of the man speaking, it's impossible to know for sure. But usually people would not say "boys" in that specific context.
Another possibility then is that he's being derogatory about the Asian man's height, since Asian men are generally shorter than people of European origin.

A white person's use of "boy" to address any man of color, can certainly be racist.  Without more context, I can't say whether it was intended that way in the referenced scene, but it seems likely.
In "The Encounter", a 1964 episode of The Twilight Zone, a white American veteran of World War II (Fenton) meets a Japanese-American man (Takamori).  At first, Takamori silently endures most of Fenton's casual uses of racial epithets, but he takes a stand after Fenton repeatedly calls him "boy."

You aren't wrong about the typical context of addressing an adult as "boy," and the example is good for demonstrating that, but as I mentioned in a comment on another answer, now moved to chat, if the context is similar to what the poster remembers, it's a lot closer to saying that there's a bathroom for boys (a men's bathroom), rather than actually addressing the interlocutor as "boy," which is a lot less clear. If the poster had remembered the dialogue as the second person actually addressing the first person as "boy," it would be pretty likely to be intended as a racist putdown.

@Obie2.0:  There are two aspects to the question.  One is whether the referenced scene portrayed a racist attitude, the other is whether "boy" used for an Eastern Asian man is derogatory in the same sense that it is when directed at a Black man.  The former is undecidable without more context.  (As quoted in the O.P., it seems likely to me that it was an indirect way of calling the character "boy".)  The latter answer is yes, as supported by the example I provided.


Racism aside, is that reply rude in another way? Can you call a man a “boy” in situations like that? I know in some situations you can call a man a “boy” without any derogatory meaning.

It's hard to know for sure what the intention of that was in the movie without more context but I think this is easily answerable.  I would avoid using the term in reference to any adult (or even adolescent) unless you are very familiar with them and know that it's OK.
When I was a teenager in the 90s, Public Enemy was a very popular rap group. One of the group's members had a famous catch-phrase: "Yeah boy" ("yeah booooyeee!"). I recall this leading to some unpleasant situations and lost friendships when this was repeated without fully understanding the negative connotation associated with 'boy'. I would especially avoid the phrase "my boy" which, while often used as a term of endearment, can also cause great offense.

So how about phrases like “that’s my boy” and words like “attaboy”? Can those be interpreted as derogatory?

@Socrates any phrase containing "boy" could be interpreted as derogatory.  Whether it's likely to be so interpreted depends on the context.

@Socrates I think in general the big risk with something like that is that it can be patronizing. It could be like calling an adult a 'kid'.
